# Only first change can Trigger event

Tags: excel, vba, events, triggers

when I open the excel and only the first chaneg can do this Trigger, please help me check.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim r As Range

Set r = Target.Cells(1, 1)

If r.Row > 2 And r.Column = 19 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Cells(r.Row, r.Column + 2) = r

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You never re-enable events after turning them off with `Application.EnableEvents = False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comments said you turn off the events and never turn them on  again. Change your code like that:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim r As Range
    
    On Error GoTo EH
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set r = Target.Cells(1, 1)

    If r.Row > 2 And r.Column = 19 Then
        Cells(r.Row, r.Column + 2) = r
    End If
    
    ' Do not add an exit sub!
EH:
    ' This part should run  in any case
    ' regardless if an error happend in the code above
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```